# undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/accounts/15":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to display a list of accounts, i am getting the above error in my `link_to` method. Below is my `link_to` method.

```
<div class="list-group">
  <% @accounts.each do |account| %>
  <%= link_to account.name, account_path( account.accountid ), 
            class: "list-group-item active" do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  <span class="badge">44</span>
  <% end %> 
  <% end %>                                                                
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using the **block form of link_to you can't have text content** (the block is your text content). If you look at [**rails helpers**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to). The syntax for block form looks like:

```
link_to(url, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end
```

So you need to do something like:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <% @accounts.each do |account| %>
    <%= link_to account_path( account.accountid ), class: "list-group-item active" do %>
      <%= account.name %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="badge">44</span>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Should it be <%= account.name %> pr just account.name